# getValues() returns 0.0 when retrieving values from cells containing references

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I am trying to retrieve values from a google spreadsheet using the line

```
var getValues = ss.getRange(range).getValues();
```

The cells whose values I want contain formulae, eg
`=sum(Detailed_Estimate!C96:O96)`, etc.

In the above case, `getValues()` is returning 0.0. However, if I hardcode the values into the cells, then the values are returning correctly as expected.

I notice that though the cells contain formulae, the underlying data for those formulae come from an `ImportRange` from another spreadsheet. Could this be causing the problem ?

Comment: I confirmed that formulae can be used without any problems. However, if I use an ImportRange then the problem occurs. I have to copy the values from the other spreadsheet instead of using ImportRange for the problem to not occur. Do not understand why this happens though.

Comment: Report it on the Apps Script Issue Tracker:  [Link to Apps Script Issue Tracker](https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/list)

Answer (score 0):

Your range parameter must be defined wrong.  the method, `getValues()` *will* return values from formulas, so you are using the correct method.

I just put some formulas into a sheet, used the following code, and got a return of an array of values:

```
function getValsTest() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var getValues = ss.getRange("D9:D13").getValues();
  Logger.log("getValues: " + getValues);
};
```

I also named a range, and referred to the named range in the parameter:

```
var getValues = ss.getRange("sumFormulas").getValues();
```

And also got values instead of formulas.

Comment: Sandy thank you for your input. I believe I am using the correct range. However the underlying data for those formulae are coming from an ImportRange. I believe that this somehow is causing this problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you use an import range, make sure that the import values you are using is set to number format. This way you don't have to copy and paste and lose your query formula. Not sure why this even happens, but same thing happened to me.